# Firebase StorageException when download

Tags: android, firebase, download, firebase-storage

I have been searching for this problem, but I have not found any solution here. My problem is that when I post new item to firebase storage everything works well, but when I try to download it, directory folder is created successfully, but file is not downloaded as it shows me this error exception:

> com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: Object does not exist at
>   location

My code here:

```
  @Override
        public void onButtonDownloadClick(View view, final int position) {
            String name = list.get(position).getRemoteName();


            File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "FromFiles");
            // Create direcorty if not exists
            if(!storagePath.exists()) {
                storagePath.mkdirs();
            }

            final File myFile = new File(storagePath, list.get(position).getRemoteName());


            islandRef = storageReference.child(uid).child("files").child(name);


            islandRef.getFile(myFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    // Local temp file has been created
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Succeed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle any errors
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

When I press button, file should be downloaded, however only directory is created.

Comment: It seems the object doesn't exist in the specified path and try the answer given by me.

Comment: path was wrong, the code is right, I am so distracted, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working example for the firebase download and check the download path, the object should exist in the bucket.

```
// Initialize Storage
        //storage
        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance("gs://<bucket_name>");
        mStorageRef = mStorage.getReference();

    final StorageReference downloadRef;
            downloadRef = mStorageRef.getRoot().child(downloadPath);

            try {
                File output = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + Config.MY_VIDEOS_PATH);
                if (!output.exists()) {
                    output.mkdir();
                }
                localFile = new File(output, downloadId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            // Download and get total bytes
            downloadRef.getFile(localFile)
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            showProgressNotification(1,title, "",
                                    taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred(),
                                    taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "download:SUCCESS");
                            // Send success broadcast with number of bytes downloaded
                            broadcastDownloadFinished(downloadPath, taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                            showDownloadFinishedNotification(downloadPath, (int) taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());

                            // Mark task completed
                            taskCompleted();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "download:FAILURE", exception);
                            Log.w(TAG, "download:FAILURE", exception.getCause());

                            // Send failure broadcast
                            broadcastDownloadFinished(downloadPath, -1);
                            showDownloadFinishedNotification(downloadPath, -1);

                            // Mark task completed
                            taskCompleted();
                        }
                    });
```

Let us assume that your image.jpg in the photos folder then the downloadPath photos/image.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Check Firebase Rules ..!

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}




private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private FirebaseDatabase mdatabase;

    private DatabaseReference mdatabaseReference;




    StorageReference mFStorage;



    StorageReference filePath;


     mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            mdatabaseReference = mdatabase.getReference();
            mFStorage= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();





    filePath=mFStorage.child("audio").child(audioId+".mp3");

            filePath.putFile(imageGalleryUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    dialog.dismiss();

                    DownloadUrl=taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    Log.d(TAG,"DownloadUrl.toString()");





                    //download link for file



                }
            });
```

then use Download Manager To download File like for Audio

```
Context ctx=MainActivty.this;

     DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)ctx.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);



                                                                    //Your Url here

            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
            request.setDescription("Downloading a file");
            long id =  downloadManager.enqueue(request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI |DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                    .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
                    .setTitle("File Downloading...")
                    .setDescription("Audio File Downloading...!")
                    .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "/Audio/"+audioName+".mp3"));
```