# "Firebase storage exception: object does not exist" I don't know why

Tags: android, firebase

Firebase storage Exception occurs. The object is said to not exist But when I checked the debug window and the Firebase console, it's there. Please help me.

I tried the "Glide" library, but the "Using" method was not available. I also tried using the "FirebaseImageLoader" and "load" methods, but failed. I want to connect the image to ImageView without using the "Glide" library.

```java
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
StorageReference photoReference= storageReference.child("Image/"+fileName);

final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

photoReference.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                   Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                   imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Such file or Path found!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

The value (url) of the "photoReference" is the same as the "storage location" of my image in the Firebase Console. So why does the exception occur that the object does not exist? I'm very curious.

Comment: simply pass url to glide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check following answer
[Firebase StorageException when download](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44178997/11086286)

Comment: Nothing helped me.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)